# Error in playing sound in the browser using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am getting this error my sound was not working initially then started working even I didn't do anything and now it has stopped working again

Piece of code:
var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + randomChosenColor + ".mp3");
audio.play();

this is the error message I am getting:
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

Answer (score 0):

Check the browser [Autoplay Policies](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).

> As you may have noticed, web browsers are moving towards stricter autoplay policies in order to improve the user experience, minimize incentives to install ad blockers, and reduce data consumption on expensive and/or constrained networks. These changes are intended to give greater control of playback to users and to benefit publishers with legitimate use cases.